# Doubling individual list values in a python list

Tags: python, list

Let's say:

list =  [ 2, 4, 6, 11]

What's the quickest way to convert that list to list = [4, 8, 12, 22] ?

Comment: What do you mean "quickest"? Lowest time complexity? Shortest code? What, if anything, have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
list = [x * 2 for x in list]
```

Also, don't name your variables after built-in functions as they will shadow the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [map()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map). A map function receives a **list** and a function **f( )**, and it consist on applying **f( )** on each element of the **list** and appends the result to a list that would be the object returned

```
foos = [2,4,6,11]
def f(foo):
    return foo*2
result = map(f, foos)
print result
```

Answer (score -1):

Using python `lambda`

```
>>> list = [ 2, 4, 6, 11]
>>> list
[2, 4, 6, 11]
>>> map(lambda x:x*2, list)
[4, 8, 12, 22]
```